# I'm creating a project with 2 classes (person & contact with a GUI output.

Tags: java, swing

I keep getting this error message:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself ...

my GUI code is...

```
package edu.cvtc.java;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @author Big Dogg
 *
 */
public class CustomerContact extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7308354216451193491L;

private List<CustomerContact> customer = new ArrayList<>();

private JTextField firstName = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField lastName = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField birthDate = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField emailAddress = new JTextField(15);
private JTextField phoneNumber = new JTextField(12);

private static final JLabel FIRST_NAME_LABEL = new JLabel("First Name: ");
private static final JLabel LAST_NAME_LABEL = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
private static final JLabel BIRTH_DATE_LABEL = new JLabel("Birth Date: ");
private static final JLabel EMAIL_ADDRESS_LABEL = new JLabel("Email Address: ");
private static final JLabel PHONE_NUMBER_LABEL = new JLabel("Phone Number: ");

private JPanel firstNamePanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel lastNamePanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel birthDatePanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel emailAddressPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel phoneNumberPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

private JButton addCustomer = new JButton("Add Customer");

public CustomerContact() {
    super("Customer Contact");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));

    firstNamePanel.add(FIRST_NAME_LABEL);
    firstNamePanel.add(firstName);

    lastNamePanel.add(LAST_NAME_LABEL);
    lastNamePanel.add(lastName);

    birthDatePanel.add(BIRTH_DATE_LABEL);
    birthDatePanel.add(birthDate);

    emailAddressPanel.add(EMAIL_ADDRESS_LABEL);
    emailAddressPanel.add(emailAddress);

    phoneNumberPanel.add(PHONE_NUMBER_LABEL);
    phoneNumberPanel.add(phoneNumber);

    addCustomer.addActionListener(new AddCustomerListener());
    addCustomer.addActionListener(new ShowCustomerListener());

    buttonPanel.add(addCustomer);

    add(firstNamePanel);
    add(lastNamePanel);
    add(birthDatePanel);
    add(emailAddressPanel);
    add(phoneNumberPanel);
    add(buttonPanel);

    pack();

    setVisible(true);
}

private class AddCustomerListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        CustomerContact customer = new CustomerContact();
        customer.add(customer);
        firstName.setText("");
        lastName.setText("");
        birthDate.setText("");
        emailAddress.setText("");
        phoneNumber.setText("");

    }                   

}

private class ShowCustomerListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {         
        System.out.println(customer);
    }                   

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

new CustomerContact();      
}

}
```

What am i missing to cause the exception error??

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a component to itself:

```
customer.add(customer);
```

That doesn't make sense. Add it somewhere else instead.

Comment: I change it to:
customers.add(customer); (forgot the "s")
But now my display is ... empty just shows []..??

Comment: @user3602810: You should probably ask that as a new question if you want any attention. Remember to trim your code down to the relevant part and post a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message will tell you *exactly* which line is wrong, and is telling *exactly* **why**, so look at it critically. It's telling you that you can't add a container's parent to itself like you're trying to do here:

```
customer.add(customer);
```

makes no sense to try to add something to itself.

Solution: don't do this. More important, read the error messages critically for they will usually lead you to a solution.

Comment: I change it to:
customers.add(customer); (forgot the "s")
But now my display is ... empty just shows []..??